# Scale image element in SVG to fit the SVG dimensions

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have an image element inside an SVG element. The href attribute of the image element and the width and height of the SVG element is set dynamically in JavaScript. I want the image element to fill up the parent SVG element.

```
<svg id="mySVG">
  <svg:g>
    <image id="bgImg" width="100%" height="100%"></img>
    ...
  </svg:g>
</svg>
```

Basically, I want the image element to be set as a background image of the SVG element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some examples. Most likely you need to make the size of the image match the viewBox of the svg.

Depending on your use case you can use [preserveAspectRatio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio) to control how the image behaves inside the SVG:

```css
svg {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<p>Without setting the size:</p>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <image href="https://via.placeholder.com/150"/>
</svg>
<p>The size of the image matches the viewBow of the SVG:</p>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 150 150">
  <image href="https://via.placeholder.com/150"/>
</svg>
<p>And then control the size of the SVG with a width (or height) attribute:</p>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 150 150" width="100">
  <image href="https://via.placeholder.com/150"/>
</svg>
<p>Same as above but with a viewBox that does not fit the size of the image and therefore the size of the image needs to be set explicitly:</p>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="100">
  <image href="https://via.placeholder.com/150" width="100" height="100"/>
</svg>
<p>Force the image to match the viewBox with preserveAspectRatio = none:</p>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 300 150">
  <image href="https://via.placeholder.com/150" width="300" height="150" preserveAspectRatio="none"/>
</svg>
```